# restore dd image to another usb stick failed

Tags: fat32, dd, ext3

I'm trying to create a dd image which contains two partition.
The first is a ext3,(19MB) the 2nd is fat32.(16MB)

I use one 512M usb stick to create image. And use

```
dd if=/dev/sdc of=image.dd bs=1M count=35  # 35=19+16
```

I tried to put it on another 2G usb stick by

```
dd if=image.dd of=/dev/sdb bs=1M
```

Then I try to use gparted to view the partition on /dev/sdb.
The ext3 partition is OK. But the fat32 partition failed.
I've compared the MBR between sda & sdb they are same.

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=image2.dd bs=1M
```

diff image.dd image2.dd 
Binary files sdb.dd and sdc.dd differ

It is very strange, even when I just read the written image, it is different.

```
dd if=image.dd of=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=35
dd of=image2.dd if=/dev/sdb bs=1M count=35
diff image.dd image2.dd 
differ
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem resides in not thinking about the space the MBR needs: The MBR consists of 512 or more bytes located in the first sector of the drive.

Since dd is using the exact size of the partitions, but you're not adding the MBR size, you're ending with a partially complete image. Add 1 more to the count to be able to save all the information.

```
dd if=/dev/sdc of=image.dd bs=1M count=36
```

If you want to narrow the size more, you could play with bs/count values by lowering the block size and finding the right block count.

Answer (score 0):

Add an option **oflag=direct** on dd. It works now.